# Chrome extension: how do I do modify DOM of a determinate page with contextMenus?

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

As title, how to be able to apply the modifications to another page, different from that of background?

Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extensione tha I made",
    "permissions":["contextMenus", "tabs", "http://localhost/CreativaIly/*"],
    "background_page": "background_page.html",
    "browser_action":{ 
                        "name": "My First Extension!",
                        "default_icon": "Chrome_icon32bn.png",
                        /*"default_popup": "popup.html",*/
                        "default_title": "My First Extension!"
    },
    "icons": {
                "16": "Chrome_icon19color.png",
                "48": "Chrome_icon32color.png",
                "128": "Chrome_icon.png"
    }
}
```

Background page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Background Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.4.2-full-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I strongly recommend reading about [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) as the solution involves the combination of these 2 techniques.

I could do a quick solution for you using these techniques but you'd probably fall in to a pitfall later on because you didn't study these pages. However, I will give you a basic example flow;

- Setup the manifest to inject a content script in to all pages that manipulates the DOM in the way you want when [chrome.extension.onRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#event-onRequest) is fired
- Create your [context menu](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) and listen for click events
- When [onclick](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create) is fired capture the `tab.id` and use it to call [chrome.tabs.sendRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendRequest)

It's a lot simpler than it may first appear.

Comment: Ok, i thought that non there was requests need Ajax, so still i did not read guide's this part.
Thanks, I will conduct with it a study.